# Condition in Css with Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css

Can we have Variable pass the value Black and it will condtion in css

I have one Master page :   in that page i am using

one variable which comes to database and than if variable data's value is black than the value is check in css file and than dynamic background color should display .

Css with asp.net

abc.cs 
here one variable getcolor 
if the variable getcolor ="Black"
or any value 
than the css code is selected

Iwant to

if(getcolor ="Black")
{

}
else
{

}

Comment: paste here your pieces of code

Answer (score 0):

May be, you can write your background style inline

```
<div style="background-color: <% If getcolor = "Black" Then Response.Write "black" Else Response.Write "AnyColor" %>;">
```